# A way to reduce and optimize this code in C#

Tags: c#, .net

As everyone known c# is strongly typed language.

This have the pros and cons.

I have this code that work fine without problems:

```
   public static void SetText(Button Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(CheckBox Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(ComboBox Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(Label Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(LinkLabel Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(RadioButton Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
   public static void SetText(TextBox Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }

   public static String GetText(Button Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(CheckBox Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(ComboBox Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(Label Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(LinkLabel Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(RadioButton Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
   public static String GetText(TextBox Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
```

The easy way to reduce this code is something like this:

```
public static void SetText(Object Obj, string Text) { Obj.Text = Text; }
public static String GetText(Object Obj) { return Obj.Text; }
```

but is don't work becouse c# is a strict language about the type.

To solve the problem I could use reflections but I don't want do it.

If there is an altenative I can reduce much code otherwise I must do it for other functions.

Some idea ?

Comment: If any of the above types (Button, Checkbox) derive from the same baseclass or implement the same interface that has a Text property, you just can create one method and use the polymorphism like this:
`public static void SetText(BaseTypeOrInterfaceThatHasTextProperty obj, string text) {
    obj.Text = text;
}`

Comment: What, exactly, is the *point* of this code?

Answer (score 11):

Every element in your code is derived from `Windows.Forms.Control` which has a `Text` property.

```
public static void SetText(Control ctrl, string text) { ctrl.Text = text; }
public static String GetText(Control ctrl)            { return ctrl.Text; }
```

(Note that the standard .NET naming conventions recommend using lowercase names for parameters.)

Comment: What about static properties?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov please, clarify your question. What static properties do you mean and what about them?

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch, that parameter was passed in. I just thought about further simplification. Something like extension method to `Control`

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry's answer is great and I just was in extend it little bit.

Assuming you have non-trivial logic in each method (because why do you need them, if you can access `Text` property on `Control` class directly), you can take advantage of extension methods in C#. They where added since `C# 3.0` version

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
     public static void SetText(this Control ctrl, string text) 
     { 
          ctrl.Text = text;
     }

     public static String GetText(this Control ctrl)            
     { 
          return ctrl.Text;
     }
}
```

In case of simple static methods, you call would look like:

```
YourStaticClass.SetText(myControl, "some text");
```

but using extension method syntax, you can write next code on any object, derived from `Control` class.

```
myControl.SetText("some text");
```

and the static method `SetText` will be called